# show product review in virtuemart and joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla, product, virtuemart, review

How to enable the view of product review(for end users) for a product in the product details page for virtuemart in joomla 1.5 ?

Comment: which version of virtuemart are you using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable the product review like the given navigation below:

**For Joomla 1.5 and virtuemart 1.1.9 stable** the navigations are:

> Go to components->com_virtuemart->configuration->global->Auto-Publish
>   Reviews?

Just enable it. You have your solution. You can refer this image :
[image]

**For Joomla 2.5 and virtuemart 2.0.16 stable** the navigations are:

> Go to
>   components->com_virtuemart->configuration->shopfront->Auto-Publish
>   Reviews?

[image]

Comment: OK thanks for the reply. Now in flypage-ask.tpl.php file, how to fetch all the reviews I mean what will be the variable name for showing all reviews. Could you please help me?